# Хеширование паролей в базе несколькими способами

Tags: хеширование, пароль

Задался таким вопросом, что если для хеширования паролей использовать несколько способов хеширования. Допустим будет 5 разных способов хеширования, они будут псевдорандомно выбираться для пароля и сохраняться в базу. Насколько это будет эффективно? Использовал ли кто-то это или очень плохой способ?

Comment: вы хоть напишите какую целью преследуете, чтобы такое делать?

Comment: Зачем использовать несколько способов, если можно выбрать один самый безопасный?

Comment: Типо если база данных уйдет то пароль будет сложнее узнать потому что он может быть хеширован 1 из 5 способов. Поэтому и спрашиваю эффективно ли это.

Comment: В этом нет смысла, достаточно использовать один самый надёжный способ, чтобы полностью исключить на практике возможность узнавания пароля